# vs code not showing autocomplete working for all commands of js except for commands which include modules

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

[here console is showing auto-complete but ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPMPm.png)
[but here fs. is not showing any auto-complete option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX4fU.png)

auto-complete is working for all other language(c++,java, c).
also for javascript but when using modules not working

please help.....

enabled all auto-complete but still same

Comment: don't make me retype your code to reproduce the behaviour. screenshots are useful here, but you should still give the code as text as well. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541 and the instructions for providing a [mre].

Comment: did you install [`@types/node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) yet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.